# strange jquery function behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code inserted before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.header-search-form, .hoverbgpfthnailiface ').click(function(e){

            var target = e.target;
            while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

            if(target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA'){
                jQuery('.header-search-form').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
                jQuery('.imgcontainer').show();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that the script is not working, I checked the console and no errors. 
The strange this is that if I put this code in Chrome console it's working perfect.

What's wrong ?

[Here](http://whiteandgold.ro/ipp/) is the website if helps with something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could at least explain what is supposed to do

Comment: Works for me in Firefox. Might be a browser specific thing if it is not working in other browsers. On a related note, you have a ton of JS at the bottom of the page that will perform better (from a caching perspective) if you move it into external JS references.

Comment: You need to be more specific at what is intended function of this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$(document).load` or `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready`

if you must leave it before closing body tag, then also , in addition to the above [assume usage of `$(window).load` instead of $(document).ready ], add this line  at the end of your code right before closing script tag: `$(window).trigger('load');`

Comment: I've tried with `$(window).load` without the `$(window).trigger('load'); ` and it works, thank you!

Comment: I'd advise against triggering window.load arbitrarily.  What if another script on the page (author's, library, third-party, whatever) is set to run after all the images on the page have finished loading? In the above scenario, you've triggered that event whether or not those images have finished loading.

Comment: So, what do you reccomend using instead of `$(window).load` ?

Comment: I thought it would work without the triggering, and it indeed did for Alecs. Was not sure if it would work if right before closing body tag without a trigger, but luckily it does not need trigger. @ethagnawl u are right it is not good to TRIGGER it arbitraily, though in Alecs case he got it to work without doing that (he said he did NOT need to use $(window).trigger('load') - he said he didn't have to trigger it so I think it's all good here. It looks like as I suspected changing it to listen for $(window).load worked for Alecs whereas $(document).ready did not work.